# Severity level of test in Allure report for C# + SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

I want to implement feature "Severity" of the Allure framework for my SpecFlow tests. The feature is described here https://docs.qameta.io/allure/.

I haven't found in docs how to implement it for C# or for SpecFlow.

Please share your ideas.

`@severity=blocker` on the specflow scenario didn't work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tag works in my solution:

```
@blocker
Scenario:...
```

**allureConfig.json** file should contain next data:

```
  "labels": {
     "owner": "^owner:?(.+)",
      "severity": "^(normal|blocker|critical|minor|trivial)"
    },
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks!)

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Please share versions you use. I use SpecFlow 2.4.0, Allure  2.4.1.1

Comment: Specflow: 2.4.0, Specflow.Allure: 2.4.1.1. Having this in allure.config (already was present):  "labels": {
      "owner": "^owner:?(.+)",
      "severity": "^(normal|blocker|critical|minor|trivial)"
    },

Comment: Thanks, would be good if you add your comment to your answer. config for allureConfig.json helped!